# ERROR: Schema "x" does not exist

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm attempting to select the users from a 'users' table that have the most occurrences of their 'order_id' property in the 'shipments' table. This is what I've tried:

```
SELECT users.first_name, users.email, shipments.count(order_id) 
    FROM users, shipments
    WHERE shipments.order_id = users.current_order_id
    GROUP by shipments.order_id
    ORDER by shipments.count(order_id) DESC
    LIMIT 25
```

But I'm getting an error of:

```
ERROR:  schema "shipments" does not exist
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You are doing the COUNT the wrong way. The tableName and column name go inside the COUNT(). or you could do COUNT(*) in this case:

```
SELECT users.first_name, users.email, count(shipments.order_id) 
FROM users, shipments
WHERE shipments.order_id = users.current_order_id
GROUP by users.first_name, users.email
ORDER by count(shipments.order_id) DESC
LIMIT 25
```

Also, you should be doing GROUP BY the columns that you select that are not the aggregate function.

Comment: Different error now: "ERROR:  column "users.first_name" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: EXPLAIN SELECT users.first_name, users.email, count(shipment..."

Comment: edited my answer. with additional information and updated query

Comment: Hmm this seems to have completely broken it! I'm getting data back, but the users returned have random numbers of matching orders. Row 1 is a user with <20 orders, but I know the top user has had 76.

Comment: The problem might be in the way your schemma was created. You have current_order_id in users table. That doesn't look like a good way to JOIN a users and shipments tables. You should probably have user_id in shipments instead. Otherwise you can only have a 1 to 1 relationship.